# Find the lower bound on the probability that the length of the wall is within 3 units of 500 units using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

A wall is to be built with 25 cement blocks. The length of the cement blocks has mean 20 and standard deviation 0.2.

Use chebyshev's inequalityt to find a lower bound on the probability that the length of the wall is within 3 of 500.

I found out that the mean of the wall is 500 and the variance of the wall is 1

Applying chebyshev's inequality, I got

$1 - P(|X−µ|≥k) = 1 -  σ^2/k^2$ which I got to be $8/9$. I'm quite confused because the answer key says that it is $2/3$.

I'm new to chebyshev's inequality, can anybody help ?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title. You are not looking for "the lower bound of a wall".